# Swift GeoFencing UILocalNotification not working

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification, geofencing

I am working on geofencing in swift. I am starting monitoring for a particular region and in my delegate method

```
locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion)
```

I am presenting a local notification like this

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    if region is CLCircularRegion {
       // mappleManager.handleRegionEvent(region)
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "Entry!"
        notification.alertAction = "be awesome!"
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        notification.userInfo = ["id": "id"];
        notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

    }
}
```

so its working fine , If I come across a region I get a local notification.

but if someone clicks this notification and app launches I want to open a another view controller  for this I am  doing

```
if(launchOptions != nil) {
        window?.rootViewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor();

        if let notification:UILocalNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification {
            window?.rootViewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
            if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
                window?.rootViewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
                if let id = userInfo["id"] as? String {
                    window?.rootViewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I dont know how to debug app launch in this case but for now I am changing the view's background color. So when I click a local notification I get cyanColor in my view, that means below line is failing

```
if let notification:UILocalNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? UILocalNotification {
            //code here
        }
```

because I wrote the cyan color code right above to this line.

here I am not getting why its failing as its clear that notification is UILocalNotification then why this line is failing.

one more this I want to tell  that its only happening In case of geo fens it I schedule same notification from my viewDidLoad after 20 sec and then close the app it works fine but if I show it from

```
locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion)
```

then it gives me cyan color.

can any buddy help me where I am mistaking?